# #1072 - Key column 'Name' doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ban` (

`UID` int(4) NOT NULL,

`AdminUID` int(4) NOT NULL,

`Grund` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`Datum` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`IP` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`Serial` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`Eintragsdatum` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

`STime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
,
PRIMARY KEY (`UID`),
KEY `Name` (`Name`),
KEY `IP` (`IP`),
KEY `Serial` (`Serial`),
KEY `STime` (`STime`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Error:

## 1072 - Key column 'Name' doesn't exist in table

Where is my fault?

Comment: Where is my fault? - you're supposed to read the error message.

Comment: `Name`, there is no such column and you are creating key on it. `KEY Name (Name)`

Comment: what I need to change?

Comment: Add a column name or don't add a Key using Name.

Answer (score 0):

Remove KEY Name (Name) in the code as there is not Name field in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ban (

UID int(4) NOT NULL,

AdminUID int(4) NOT NULL,

Grund varchar(50) NOT NULL,

Datum varchar(50) NOT NULL,

IP varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

Serial varchar(50) NOT NULL,

Eintragsdatum timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

STime int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' , PRIMARY KEY (UID), KEY IP (IP), KEY Serial (Serial), KEY STime (STime) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: yea i have add a column name . Thanks